# eb.exe deploy": Errno 13 Permission denied: './pagefile.sys'

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

I am compiling a website using [TeamCity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity) on a server and need to deploy the compiled website to AWS.

As my last build step, I use the [Elastic Beanstalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Elastic_Beanstalk) CLI to deploy: "C:\Python34...\eb.exe deploy".

`eb init` has already been run...but whenever I run "eb deploy", (even when I run it from the command line in an empty directory--which should deploy a default project to AWS), an error appears saying:

> Error: PermissionError :: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './pagefile.sys'

I have already run the command on my local machine without any problems; I receive the error on the server regardless of whether I am running the command line as an administrator.

I am wondering if this is a permissions issue with the server, or something else? I haven't been able to achieve much insight from the other questions, because they seem to have been solved on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: isn't some other process using that file on the server?

Comment: I don't know. seems like it should work the same on my local pc as it does on the server...but why it needs to access the pagefile...?

Comment: The error implies the working directory is the root of the drive. eb.exe could be opening files in the initial working directory to look for something. In that case a workaround would be to run with a different working directory.

Answer (score 1):

`pagefile.sys` is the Windows [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) file.

It is a special file which cannot be written or manipulated. Whatever your command is doing you need to fix your command so it that doesn't touch this file and ignores it.

Comment: seems strange that it would be trying to access the swap file.  just running a standard command that works fine on the local machine.

Comment: @bordeo: Unless stackoveflow gives any useful replies, I suggest you reach out for `eb.exe` authors and issue tracker.