# eb create: ERROR: PermissionError - [Errno 13] Permission denied: './catroot2\\edb.log'

Tags: django, windows, amazon-web-services, windows-services

I'm new to this server set up. Let me get to the point: I had this Django project I want to deploy on AWS, and I follow the document in link: *[Deploying a Django Application to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html)*

But when I reach the part on (**To create an environment and deploy your Django application**)

Point 3. **Create an environment and deploy you application to it with eb create:**

I had these problems:

```
(FATWebsite) C:\WINDOWS\system32>eb create django-env
Creating application version archive "app-190212_105329".
ERROR: PermissionError - [Errno 13] Permission denied: './catroot2\\edb.log'
```

From Google, *[eb.exe deploy": Errno 13 Permission denied: './pagefile.sys'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277749/eb-exe-deploy-errno-13-permission-denied-pagefile-sys/31279057#31279057)*, it seems to me that `'./catroot2\\edb.log'` is a special file which cannot be written or manipulated.

But I do not know of any answer to resolve this issue.

And I can't submit ticket to AWS for help (because that plan service).

Comment: Your OS of `elasticbeanstalk` instance is Windows? Or Linux?

Comment: Windows, using pip install

Comment: Why you run command in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\` not in your project dir? Did you tried to run command in your project directory?

Comment: I'm not really sure where to run command, but i did use virtual-env to run.

Comment: Did you run django server in local by `runserver` command? Then, where are there?  You must run your command in your `project_dir`. Now you are in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.

Comment: django on local server yes. Is run by the {Runserver} comand, as for the project-dir are place in virtual-env; where active it and try running there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188256/discussion-between-yongjin-jo-and-im-a-it-dumb-head).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the command being typed in the wrong path. `catroot2\edb.log` is a file in `C:\WINDOWS\system32` and only an administrator user can access this file. So `elasticbeanstalk` can not access that file.

The problem was resolved when he typed the command from the correct path.